# fstream accepts folder path and is (`good()==1`)

Tags: c++, fstream

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

int main()
{

std::string folderPath("./");

std::string fileFoo = folderPath + "";
std::string fileBar = folderPath + "nonexisting_file"; 

std::ifstream foo(fileFoo.c_str());
std::ifstream bar(fileBar.c_str());

std::cout << foo.good() << std::endl;
std::cout << bar.good() << std::endl;

}
```

Output:

```
1
0
```

1. What does it mean the stream file path is a directory.
2. How to check that `fstream` is readable in this case, since `good()` does not work.

**Edit**:

This seems relavant:

Platform: Linux (Ubuntu 12.04)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the file system it may easily be the case that a directory **is** a kind of file and is not much different. And as handling what you try to do will not be platform independent unless you use some third party library I strongly recommend using `boost::filesystem`.

Comment: I am Linux. Can you provide resource.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/tutorial.html) will help you?